# I can't control an instance of cmd in c#

Tags: c#, cmd, instance, handle

So i have this code:

```
process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.Start();
streamWriter = process.StandardInput;
```

And when i run the app a cmd console appears but it says "The handle is invalid." And if i try and use the streamWriter to write something i get the message of invalid handle about four times per try.

Also the normal copywrite Microsoft stuff at the beginning is missing as well.

What could be the problem?

If i try and use the Windows Shell, not redirecting the streams just creating a process of cmd, a normal cmd console appears and i can type in it without a problem.

EDIT:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();
sw = process.StandardInput;
sr = process.StandardOutput;

sw.WriteLine("echo 123");

MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());

process.WaitForExit();
}
```

So now a blank cmd pops up and i have to manually close it and only then i get the information out of it, BUT i don't want to lose this instance of cmd so what can i do to keep it 'alive' and keep 'talking' to it?

Edit#2
So by 'alive' i meant how can i make it so i don't have to close it to get my information out of it, do i have to use threads ? because it seems to me that the GUI is hanging/waiting for the cmd to close :/

Comment: This works as expected from a console app. Does your app have a console?

Comment: No, this code resides in an event handler for a button. I'm using WPF is that a problem ? And i'm trying to send it command lines from a text box and update another text box with the output from the cmd.

Comment: Well, I don't know about that. Sorry.

Comment: can you show the EventHandler of where this code is suppose to happen.. it appears that you are not passing and or using the console app's static methods / Events properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A WPF application doesn't have a console window.  You need to create one if you want to have one.

An existing thread on this is below:

[How to write to a console window from a windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943040/how-to-write-to-a-console-window-from-a-windows-application)

Comment: I need more time experimenting with the info you gave me, kinda strange that i can't control a cmd this easily.